# TortoiseSVN asks for the credentials on Windows

Tags: windows, tortoise-svn

I want to commit the work done in my local repo but when I am committing TortoiseSVN asks for the credentials.

I am giving GitHub username and pasword, but TortoiseSVN asks for credentials again and again. Can somebody advise?

I reinstalled TortoiseSVN and also tried clearing the authentication data in saved data submenu.

[image]

Comment: If it is asking for credentials when committing it probably wants your local machine’s credentials. Why? Unsure. But none of this sounds like your Git credentials are needed.

Comment: I tried with my system's password , still did not work.

Comment: Have you managed to find username and password that work? If the problem is that it doesn't save Authentication data, try in *TortoiseSVN settings > Advanced* to set *AllowAuthSave*.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem today. It looks like the simple authentication has been disabled so you need to setup a [Personal Access Token via GitHub](https://github.com/settings/tokens).

Generate a new one, give it a name and then select all the rights you need. Then click Generate Token. Once saved copy the long string i.e. `aae75c805fa8eea8d3e322781bc2010224e0934d` and use this as both username and password when using TortoiseSVN.

Comment: This seems to have stopped working. Did the instructions change?

Comment: Jeez... it is August 2021 and I came here for the same damn problem. Solved after generating the key.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps quickly.

Comment: It's March, 2023... and came again. Forgot the solution!